# GCSToSFTPOperator wildcard no longer working

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running into a problem where GCSToSFTPOperator is no longer working after an update of Airflow and I cannot figure out what to change to make it work again.

I am trying to retrieve multiple files from a bucket on the google cloud and store it on an FTP.

In my DAG I'm running this step:

```
# Adding the import in case it's relevant
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_sftp import GCSToSFTPOperator

GCSToSFTPOperator(
    sftp_conn_id=DEFAULT_SFTP_CONN,
    task_id="export_output_files_to_sftp",
    destination_path="/FTP_dir/Output/,
    source_bucket="bucket_name",
    source_object="folder_name/*.ndjson",
    keep_directory_structure=False,
    retries=2,
    move_object=move_object)
```

This worked before the update, but now it returns the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_sftp.py", line 156, in execute
    self._copy_single_object(gcs_hook, sftp_hook, source_object, destination_path)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_sftp.py", line 196, in _copy_single_object
    sftp_hook.store_file(destination_path, tmp.name)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/sftp/hooks/sftp.py", line 250, in store_file
    conn.put(local_full_path, remote_full_path, confirm=confirm)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 759, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 714, in putfo
    with self.file(remotepath, "wb") as fr:
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 857, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 909, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 942, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(text)
OSError: Specified file is a directory.
```

Is there a way to change my parameters so this works again or do I need to do a workaround?

Before the update we were running composer-1.20.12-airflow-2.4.3. After the update it is composer-2.5.3-airflow-2.6.3.

Comment: The functional of `GCSToSFTPOperator` provided by [`apache-airflow-providers-google`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/index.html) so I would recommend check Google Provider change log, maybe it is already fixed, or it is intended new behaviour. I also would recommend provide a bit more details previous version of provider, current version and also task logs.

Comment: I added the version that we're currently working with. Unfortunately I don't know the version we had before.

Thanks for the links, I will try to find a solution in there.

Comment: I edited some more information into the question, because I did figure out what version we were using before the update